# Java programming User defined class

Tags: java

I am new to programming. In this programming I have created a user defined public class called NumberOfGoals which contain a data declation called goalscored. It has a constructor called NumberOfGoal which is a public. When it is called, it set goalScored to 5. It also have setGoal and getGoal method. Then I create a driver class called GoalTracker which instantiate and create goal1, goal2 and goal3 objects. I have saved the file in name GoalTracker.java. But when i execute the file, I get error as shown below:

**GoalTracker.java:1: error: class NumberOfGoals is public, should be declared in a file named NumberOfGoals.java
public class NumberOfGoals
       ^
1 error**

Could you please help me??

But when i ommitted the word "public" from the "public class NumberOfGoals"(user defined class), it seems to execute. Please do brief why did it execute when I deleted the word public.

```
   public class NumberOfGoals 
{
      public  int goalsScored;

       public NumberOfGoals(){
            goalsScored= 5; 
        }
       public void setGoal() {
          goalsScored++; 
       }
       public int getGoal() {
          return goalsScored;
       }
  }
   public class GoalTracker
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NumberOfGoals goal = new NumberOfGoals();
        NumberOfGoals goal2 = new NumberOfGoals();
        NumberOfGoals goal3 = new  NumberOfGoals();
        goal.setGoal();
        System.out.println(goal.getGoal());
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java, you can define multiple top level classes in a single file, providing that at most one of these is public, check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6

Answer (score 0):

## Create class GoalTracker in a separeted file!

As the exception says,

> *[...] should be declared in a file named NumberOfGoals.java*

But, you can have an `inner class` just like you did. Todo so, just remove the `public` access modifier in GoalTrakcer class.

Here's a documentation example and guides about [Inner and Nested Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

### Inner Class Solution

Here we have one file named `NumberOfGoals.java`

```
  public class NumberOfGoals {
      public  int goalsScored;

       public NumberOfGoals(){
            goalsScored= 5; 
        }

       // Getters and Setters ommited

  }

  class GoalTracker {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          NumberOfGoals goal = new NumberOfGoals();
          NumberOfGoals goal2 = new NumberOfGoals();
          NumberOfGoals goal3 = new  NumberOfGoals();
          goal.setGoal();
         System.out.println(goal.getGoal());
     }

  }
```

### Separated class solution

Here, we need 2 files, one called `NumberOfGoals.java` and the other one called `GoalTracker.java` and now we can declare `public` access value.

#### NumberOfGoals.java

```
  public class NumberOfGoals {
      public  int goalsScored;

       public NumberOfGoals(){
            goalsScored= 5; 
        }

       // Getters and Setters ommited

  }
```

#### GoalTracker.java

```
  public class GoalTracker {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          NumberOfGoals goal = new NumberOfGoals();
          NumberOfGoals goal2 = new NumberOfGoals();
          NumberOfGoals goal3 = new  NumberOfGoals();
          goal.setGoal();
         System.out.println(goal.getGoal());
     }

  }
```